# What is a simple(non-compound) proposition(sentence/assertion) which is true called?

Tags: terminology

This might be too basic a question to ask.
I tried to find the term for this, I couldn't find one.

What is the term for a proposition which is $True$, like the following:

- $3 > 2$
- $10 + 1 = 11$
- $-3 \in \mathbb{Z}$

I've learned that the term ***tautology*** means a compound proposition which is $True$, e.g. $x > 3 \implies x > 2$. Can I use this term for the non-compound propositions like the above three examples which are $True$ as well?

Comment: [Atomic proposition](https://www.britannica.com/topic/atomic-proposition), in general: not necessarily True.

Comment: [Tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) in logic  is a formula or assertion that is true in every possible interpretation. Thus, it is the formal counterpart of "logical law".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for the introduction of the term *atomic proposition*. But what I am looking for is ones that are already true as in the 3 examples I listed in the post. *Atomic propositions* seem to be a mathematical sentence which can be either true or false when evaluated.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Isn't $x>3 \implies x>2$ a case of tautology?